# Need a login page without ons-splitter

Tags: user-interface, onsen-ui

How can I have a ons-splitter only appearing after the login page?

I have a splitter menu and four more pages, all of them need to open this splitter. But before all of it, I have a login page that I want to prevent the splitter to open (swipeable)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 common ways through which you can do this:

1. Using `ons-navigator` - you can have a navigator with the login page and then load a page with a splitter.

   After that you can just use `mySplitterContent.load('oneOf4Pages.html')`.
2. Always use `mySplitterContent.load('somePage.html')`, but by default use something like `<ons-splitter-side side="left" collapse>`.

   Later when the user logs in you can do:

   ```
   mySplitterContent.open(); 
   mySplitterContent.setAttribute('swipeable', 'swipeable');
   // and then continue using 
   mySplitterContent.load('somePage.html');
   ```